# How to make rsync delete directories from destination that are not in the source list

Tags: rsync

I want to be able to sync files from multiple directories to one directory.  If I remove a directory from the source list, then I want that directory and all of its files to be removed from the destination.

Here's a quick sample:

```
mkdir dir1
touch dir1/file1
mkdir dir2
touch dir2/file2
mkdir dir3
rsync -a dir1 dir2 dir3
```

dir3 now contains "dir1/file1" and "dir2/file2".

If I rsync again, and remove dir2 from the list:

```
rsync -a dir1 dir3
```

Then I would like dir2/file2 and dir2 to be removed from the destination.

The --delete option to rsync only handles deletes between dir1 and dir3/dir1, so dir2 remains (even if using --delete).

I've looked through the various option in the man page for rsync, and I don't see any option that tells rsync to "combine" all the sources and consider them as "one" tree so that "--delete" would do what I want it to do.  However, I'm pretty confident I'm not the first person to want to do something like this.

Ideas?

Comment: I think it's not possible using the syntax that you want. I think you nail it with your last paragraph. `rsync` doesn't "know" about `dir2`, so it won't delete it.

Comment: It's just not clear to me why rsync doesn't have an option which makes it consider all the sources as one master source.  That would solve the problem.  However, that may be addressed below by Freddy...

Answer (score 2):

The `--delete` flag obviously doesn't work if you sync multiple source directories to one destination directory. Instead of syncing `dir1` and `dir2` to `dir3` you could sync the content of the parent dir of `dir1` and `dir2`.

Example (using rsync flag `-i` to see the changes):

```
$ mkdir -p dir12/dir1 dir12/dir2 dir3
$ touch dir12/dir1/file1 dir12/dir2/file2
$ rsync -ai dir12/ dir3
cd+++++++++ dir1/
>f+++++++++ dir1/file1
cd+++++++++ dir2/
>f+++++++++ dir2/file2
# BEFORE: dir1 and dir2 were synced to dir3
$ rm -rf dir12/dir2
$ rsync -ai --delete dir12/ dir3
*deleting   dir2/file2
*deleting   dir2/
.d..t...... ./
# AFTER: dir3/dir2 is gone
```

If you don't have a common parent directory, then `dir12/dir2` could be a symlink pointing to the real directory. With option `-L` (`--copy-links`) in the first `rsync` call you would get the same directory structure in `dir3` with `dir2` as directory (instead of a symlink). And after deleting symlink `dir12/dir2` and syncing again with `--delete` the directory `dir3/dir2` would be gone like in the example.

**EDIT:**

I fiddled a bit around and may have found a hack:

```
$ mkdir empty dir1 dir2 dir3
$ touch dir1/file1 dir2/file2
$ rsync -ai dir1 dir2 dir3
cd+++++++++ dir1/
>f+++++++++ dir1/file1
cd+++++++++ dir2/
>f+++++++++ dir2/file2
$ rsync -ai --delete empty/ dir1 dir3
*deleting   dir2/file2
*deleting   dir2/
.d..t...... ./
```

Use `empty/` as a placeholder for all directories you want to delete.

Comment: The question is unclear, but I assumed that `dir1` and `dir2` were not necessarily in the same directory. I thought about `-L`, but that potentially conflicts with `-a` from the question.

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought he could create a (fake) parent directory and use symlinks instead. For the example with symlink `dir12/dir2` I used `rsync -aiL dir12/ dir3` and that seems to work, but I haven't done any further testing with more complex setups. But... if OP knows that `dir2` will be excluded from the next sync, it might be easier to manually `rm -rf` the directory on the destination side.

Comment: Yeah manually `rm` makes more sense to me. They have to change the `rsync` command anyway.

Comment: I think there's some promise to using -L and I will experiment with that tomorrow.  Basically, I have a tool that is using rsync.  One user specifies the directories that they want synced when the tool is run.  A different user runs the tool that actually does the syn.  The initial user can change the directory lists to be synced at any time.  However, the syncing user should see the "end" result - a perfect copy with no "extra" directories.  If I build a directory containing links to all the directories first, this would work. I just wish I didn't need that extra step.

Comment: As it happens, I don't think -L will work after all. After the rsync completes, the system ensures that all synced files are mode 644 and directories 755. This would mean that someone could symlink to a file they couldn't read, then after the sync, because of -L and the permission 'fixing' they would have access to the file.  I'll have to think this through some more.

Comment: Great hack!! +1